# How to share no Open Source library on Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I want to share an Android library but unfortunately on `Bintray` I can choose only OOS licenses. Is there any other way to share the library to let users download it by `gradle` as one depndency? Or the only way is to install it manually? My repo (which is private until release) contains only compiled aar file and example app. The library is free for individual usage but for commercial it will be paid. I have an `LICENSE.txt` file (in my repo) which says that clearly and has link to the site where you can buy the software. I have already read [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) article, it is very good and explain things clearly but as far as I know this is not good option in my case becouse my library is not free at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can just provide your own Maven or Ivy repository. You can use some hosting / management software like Artifactory for this, but basically such a repository is just some files following a given structure, available through some means like e. g. `http` or pure file access. So you can e. g. just make a GitHub Git repository with the files in the correct layout, then this repository should be usable as reposiory in Gradle.

Comment: Tbh I have the repository ready, it looks the same as the twin library on ios. I forgot to mention that in iOS it is solved this way: the library is shared on CocoaPods and has "Custom" license which redirects you to the github repository (where exact LICENSE.txt file exists and says something like: "For commercial usage, a valid license is required. To purchase a license for <library_name>, please see our website..". I am looking for similar solution for Android.

Comment: I don't know IOS, so don't really understand what you mean, sry.

Comment: I ask if I can add a library to `jcenter` with no license (I saw some libraries had "Custom" but it is not avilable) becouse it is specified in the repo itself in the `txt` file

Comment: I guess yes, if you switch to a paid account. The free accounts are FOSS accounts, so only FOSS licenses are available to be selected. I'd guess if you upgrade to a paid account (you can try with a free trial) you can choose and license you like.